# Настроить терминал, чтобы при работе все команды занимали только половину рабочей области

Tags: bash, консоль, xfce4-terminal

То есть чтобы при выполнении команд текущее приглашение строки всегда было примерно посередине терминала (его размера по вертикали), а не внизу, как это часто при работе? xfce4-terminal.

Comment: а когда команда начинаем много много выводить, то в нижней части ничего не должно быть?

Comment: Можно рассмотреть два варианта: 1: всегда нижняя половина пустая. 2: при выполнении многих команд возможно стандартное полное заполнение, но после окончания приглашение строки посередине становится. Просто надоело очень часто смотреть в самый низ.

Comment: ага, вот она причина. Теперь и решение можно дать. Посмотрите на выпадающие терминалы - guake terminal или Tilda. А может просто сделать размер экрана поменьше.

Comment: может, просто, окно поменьше делать? программа *xfce4-terminal*, как и любой полноценный эмулятор терминала, понимает опцию `--geometry`. например:  `$ xfce4-terminal --geometry=80x20` (ширина 80, высота 20).

Comment: `clean` вам в помощь